# APP_CODE classes missing property elements

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio

I am trying to change the properties in `App_Code` classes to `Build Action` but the property windows do not have any option that I can change !!
Below is the screen shot of my VS2005 Pro

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

It is because you have used ***Web Site Project*** not a ***Web Application***. ASP.NET web sites do not build. 
 If you want to have `Build Action` property you should use ***Web Application Project*** instead of ***Web Sites***..

Check this may help:[Converting a Web Site Project to a Web Application Project in Visual Studio](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa983476(v=vs.100).aspx).